# Max-Height in Html Table

Tags: html, css

I create a table, and I want it's `height` be `800px`.

If it's overflow, I want to make Scroll Bar but the Titles does not scroll.

So I try to add this CSS:

```
overflow: scroll;
max-height:800px;
```

But it's not work for me. This is the entire html file. What is the problem?

CSS

```
table{
    overflow: scroll;
   text-align: center;
   margin: auto;
   max-height:800px;
}
table, td, th
{
border:1px solid green;

}
th
{
background-color:green;
color:white;
}
```

And HTML

```
<table >
  <tr>
   <th>field a</th>
   <th>field b</th>
   <th>field c</th>
   <th>field e</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>3534534</td>
   <td>עו"ש</td>
   <td>6,463</td>
   <td>4,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>3534534</td>
   <td>עו"ש</td>
   <td>6,463</td>
   <td>4,000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: apply this to parent element

Comment: Do you want to make table rows scrollable, but have column headers still in place above them?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can wrap the table in a div and give the `max-height` and `overflow: scroll` to that div

```css
.pane {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 200px;
}

table {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="pane">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>field a</th>
      <th>field b</th>
      <th>field c</th>
      <th>field e</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3534534</td>
      <td>עו"ש</td>
      <td>6,463</td>
      <td>4,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3534534</td>
      <td>עו"ש</td>
      <td>6,463</td>
      <td>4,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3534534</td>
      <td>עו"ש</td>
      <td>6,463</td>
      <td>4,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3534534</td>
      <td>עו"ש</td>
      <td>6,463</td>
      <td>4,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3534534</td>
      <td>עו"ש</td>
      <td>6,463</td>
      <td>4,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3534534</td>
      <td>עו"ש</td>
      <td>6,463</td>
      <td>4,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3534534</td>
      <td>עו"ש</td>
      <td>6,463</td>
      <td>4,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3534534</td>
      <td>עו"ש</td>
      <td>6,463</td>
      <td>4,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3534534</td>
      <td>עו"ש</td>
      <td>6,463</td>
      <td>4,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3534534</td>
      <td>עו"ש</td>
      <td>6,463</td>
      <td>4,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3534534</td>
      <td>עו"ש</td>
      <td>6,463</td>
      <td>4,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3534534</td>
      <td>עו"ש</td>
      <td>6,463</td>
      <td>4,000</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yTm3E/)

---

There's another solution at [Pure CSS Scrollable Table with Fixed Header](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html) without a wrapper div, but with an additional `thead` and `tbody` around the rows. You set the thead and tbody to `display: block` and give a `max-height` and `overflow-y` to the tbody. This lets the header stay in place when scrolling the rows. But as always, it comes with a price tag. You have to specify the column widths, because the thead and tbody are out of sync due to the `display: block`

```css
thead {
    display: block;
}
tbody {
    display: block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height:200px;
}
thead th, tbody td {
    width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>field a</th>
            <th>field b</th>
            <th>field c</th>
            <th>field e</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>3534534</td>
            <td>עו"ש</td>
            <td>6,463</td>
            <td>4,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3534534</td>
            <td>עו"ש</td>
            <td>6,463</td>
            <td>4,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3534534</td>
            <td>עו"ש</td>
            <td>6,463</td>
            <td>4,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3534534</td>
            <td>עו"ש</td>
            <td>6,463</td>
            <td>4,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3534534</td>
            <td>עו"ש</td>
            <td>6,463</td>
            <td>4,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3534534</td>
            <td>עו"ש</td>
            <td>6,463</td>
            <td>4,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3534534</td>
            <td>עו"ש</td>
            <td>6,463</td>
            <td>4,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3534534</td>
            <td>עו"ש</td>
            <td>6,463</td>
            <td>4,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3534534</td>
            <td>עו"ש</td>
            <td>6,463</td>
            <td>4,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3534534</td>
            <td>עו"ש</td>
            <td>6,463</td>
            <td>4,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3534534</td>
            <td>עו"ש</td>
            <td>6,463</td>
            <td>4,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3534534</td>
            <td>עו"ש</td>
            <td>6,463</td>
            <td>4,000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yTm3E/1/)

---

*Update:*

In the source code of that site, there are comments about IE and IE6. It sets

```css
thead tr {
    position: relative
}
```

and defines the width of the table with

```css
table {
    float: left;
    width: 740px
}
```

Wheter this is relevant for IE10, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks! that work for me in Google Chrome.(same style like JSFIddle)
but not in IE 10 . there is solution for that?

Comment: I don't have IE10, so I cannot say. When you look at the source of that site, there are comments about IE6. See updated answer.

Comment: FYI, the second option does not work with column widths defined using percents.  But `em`, `rem`, and `vw` appear to work well for the jsfiddle example.

Comment: How to stretch the table to 100% and keep each column to have equal width (25%) in this case?

Comment: @Felix You may try for both the table and wrapper `width: 100%;`, and for `th, td` give `width: 25%;`

Comment: @OlafDietsche, I have tried that, but could not make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/felix111/mpa6dqLs/7/

Answer (score 7):

Use another element to wrap the whole table, and give those properties to him:

```
#table-limiter {
max-height:800px;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

HTML example:

```
<div id="table-limiter">
   <table>
      ...
   </table>
</div>
```

Styling table is, sometimes, a trouble :(

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach.

Add a wrapping div with CSS:

```
#set-height {
    display: inline-block;
    height:800px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JmLFz/

Comment: Hi, That's work. but I want that the titles will stay on top when I scrolling. how can I do that?
thank you!

Comment: I eyeballed it for you and updated the widths on the fixed cells: http://jsfiddle.net/JmLFz/2/

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the table in a div tag and set the height of the div to 800px with an overflow set to auto.

```
<div style="height:800px; overflow:auto;">
//Table goes here
</div>
```

Then if your table height is more than 800px a scroll bar will appear in the div and allow you to scroll through the table.