# expand table display to 100% with vertical scroll

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a table that I want to limit the height of to 200px and display a vertical scroll bar if the height of the table is greater than that.

Searching on SO, I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293492/max-height-in-html-table) with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yTm3E/1/).

I applied the css to my files and added the class name `scroll` to the table.

Unfortunately, the table does not expand to fill the width of the display.

**How do I overcome this?**

I have tried many things, but I am out of ideas. Giving the `table.scroll` css class a `width: 100%;` distorts the columns!

Here is my css code that I took from the thread/fiddle:

```
table.scroll {
    /*text-align: center;*/
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
table.scroll, table.scroll td, table.scroll th {
    border: 1px solid #8c8c8c;
}
table.scroll th {
    /*width: 100%;*/
}
table.scroll thead {
    display: block;
}
table.scroll tbody {
    display: block;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
table.scroll thead th, table.scroll tbody td {
    width: 70px;
}
```

The above css interacts with the table css I have for other tables on the test page:

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: #f9f9f9
}
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: #fff
}
.table-hover>tbody>tr:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    z-index: 1; /* used for placing the header behind the drop down menu */
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .header .arrow {
    width: 25px;
    height: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(../img/tablesorter/whi-bg.gif) no-repeat center left
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp .arrow {
    background: url(../img/tablesorter/whi-asc.gif)
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown .arrow {
    background: url(../img/tablesorter/whi-desc.gif)
}
.table-no-bottom-margin {
    margin-bottom: -20px !important;
}
```

This is the html table line of code for the srolling table:

```
<table id="resumes_saved_metadata_details_table" class="scroll table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed tablesorter table-no-bottom-margin">
```

This is what the table looks like with out the vertical scroll bar. This is how I would like the table columns displayed:

[image]

This is the current display of the table:

[image]

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody) seems to answer your question.

Comment: table.scroll { width: 100%; }

Comment: @Unfix thanks, but your suggestion has no effect.