# jQuery selectable and scrollable in table element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I followed [this](http://karolyi.github.io/ui-selectableScroll/demo.html) jquery plugin to make `scrollable` the `selectable` [element](https://jqueryui.com/selectable/) from default `jQueryUI` library.

The demo presents the list as `ul` html element, I would like to create a `table` which uses this feature. I need declare `table` width as `100%` and `td` width `50%`.

my code is:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://karolyi.github.io/ui-selectableScroll/javascripts/selectableScroll.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-ext.css">
    <style type="text/css"> 
        <style>
            .fixed_header{
                width: 100%;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            .fixed_header tr{
                width: 100%;
            }
            .fixed_header td{
                width: 50%;
            }
            .fixed_header tbody{
              display:block;
              width: 100%;
              overflow: auto;
              height: 100px;
            }
            td.ui-selecting {
              border: 1px dotted red;
            }
            td.ui-selected {
              background: red;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.fixed_header').selectableScroll({
                  filter: 'td'
                });
              });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div style="width:100%;height:300px;background:black"></div>
        <table class="fixed_header">
          <tbody>
            <tr><td>row 1-0</td><td>row 1-1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>row 2-0</td><td>row 2-1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>row 3-0</td><td>row 3-1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>row 4-0</td><td>row 4-1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>row 5-0</td><td>row 5-1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>row 6-0</td><td>row 6-1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>row 7-0</td><td>row 7-1</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

and there are a few problems. The most important is because the `scrollable` function does not work as expected (as demo example) - the `body` of `table` should be scrollable when user uses the `selectable` (currently is not). The second problem is about the `witdh` of my elements, it does not fill the 100% od window.

How is it possible to create the selectable and scrollable in table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your expected result by wrapping your table in a `<div/>`and setting the max height in there.
You will also want to remove `.fixed_header tbody{display:block;}` to get those `<td/>`'s full width.  Also, please see [Max-Height in Html Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293492/max-height-in-html-table).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#pane').selectableScroll({
    filter: 'td'
  });
});
```

```css
#pane{
    display: block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height:100px;
 }
 .fixed_header {
   width: 100%;
   border-collapse: collapse;
 }

 .fixed_header tr {
   width: 100%;
 }

 .fixed_header td {
   width: 50%;
 }

 .fixed_header tbody {
   /* display: block; */
   width: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   height: 100px;
 }

 td.ui-selecting {
   border: 1px dotted red;
 }

 td.ui-selected {
   background: red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://karolyi.github.io/ui-selectableScroll/javascripts/selectableScroll.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-ext.css">
    
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- <div style="width:100%;height:300px;background:black"></div> -->
    <div id="pane">
      <table class="fixed_header">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>row 1-0</td>
            <td>row 1-1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>row 2-0</td>
            <td>row 2-1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>row 3-0</td>
            <td>row 3-1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>row 4-0</td>
            <td>row 4-1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>row 5-0</td>
            <td>row 5-1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>row 6-0</td>
            <td>row 6-1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>row 6-0</td>
            <td>row 6-1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>row 6-0</td>
            <td>row 6-1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>row 6-0</td>
            <td>row 6-1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>row 7-0</td>
            <td>row 7-1</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Update: You may also find it usefull to look a little bit closer at [colspans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398734/colspan-all-columns) and [rowspans](https://html.com/tables/rowspan-colspan/). It appears that you are unintentionally setting the `width` of the `<td/>` elements.

Comment: unfortunately your code does not work for me (the selectable scrollbar doesnt work)

Comment: @karlperson is it your intention for the table only to be scrollable only when an `<td/>` has been selected?

Comment: no, table has a fix height so should be scrollable when noitems are selected and when items are selecting - when user select item and take cursor on the bottom of the table the scroll should work automatically (check the demo from my question, thats exactly what I want - just for table instead of list)